# How to call a promise on a set frequency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Here is what I need to solve.

- I make an HTTP call to submit a work order (request) to a remote web server.
- As a response, I get a Guid response back.
- This work order will complete at some point in time may be hours.

To check for work order completion, I need to periodically check for the completion status.

So every few seconds or minutes, I need to make another HTTP call to get the work status. If completed, I am done, I will ask for the results. If incomplete, I will call again in the next time slice.

What I currently have is not working correctly, I have hard coded the function to always return false so I can see the code working.

The code is as follows:

```
function isBatchRequestCompleted(method: string = 'POST', route: string, batchId: number): boolean {
timerPromise.then(result => {
    CheckESN.sendRequest('POST', 'api/batch/result', batchId)
        .then(result => {
            return false;

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
return false;
```

}

```
const timerPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(() => {
        console.log("timer");
        return 1;
    }), 3000);
});
```

Essentially wait 3s and check for status and the status check always return false

the calling code looks as follows:

```
    do {
             console.log('checking ...')
    }   while  (isBatchRequestCompleted('POST', 'api/batch/submit', +BatchId)  == false);
```

what I see is one "checking..." and no other console.logs.

Anyone sees how this is incorrect?

Comment: You cannot call a promise, you can only call a function.

Comment: You will want to use `await` inside that `while` condition

Comment: `setInterval()` might be your friend.

Comment: but the function isBatchRequestCompleted is not a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), which *repeatedly* calls a  function with a fixed time delay between calls.

After submitting a work order, create a timer using `setInterval` which fires requests to check the status of that work order. When it's status is completed, fetch the work order, clear the check status timer and resolve the outermost Promise.

This is a basic example of [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)).

```js
// Mock functions, simulate HTTP calls to submit and fetch a work order.
const submitWorkOrder = () => Promise.resolve()
const getWorkOrder = () => Promise.resolve({ results: 'foo' })

// - Mock function, simulates HTTP call to check work order status, 
//   after 5 tries it resolves status = 'completed'.
let i = 0
const checkWorkOrderStatus = () => 
  Promise.resolve({ status: ++i <= 5 ? 'pending' : 'completed' })

// Submit work order, poll and wait for completion and 
// resolve the work order when completed.
submitWorkOrder().then(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      checkWorkOrderStatus().then(result => {
        console.log('checked status which is', result.status)

        if (result.status === 'completed') {
          clearInterval(timer)
          getWorkOrder().then(resolve).catch(reject)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // make sure we also clear timer if 
        // checkOrderStatus rejects.
        clearInterval(timer)
        reject(err)
      })
    }, 400) // check status every 400ms.
  })
})
.then(result => {
  console.log('Work order is complete', result)    
})
```

This is not TypeScript btw, but I assume it's easy to translate.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `poll` function that accept a `checkCompletion`, and `resultRequest` functions (both should return a promise). If `checkCompletion` is resolved with `false`, the `delay()` function is called, and then it invokes `poll()` again:

```js
const delay = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

const poll = (checkCompletion, resultsRequest) =>     
  checkCompletion() // check for completion
    .then(r => r ?
      resultsRequest() : // if true get the results
      delay(1000).then(() => poll(checkCompletion, resultsRequest)) // if false delay and call poll again
    )

function isBatchRequestCompleted() {
  let i = 0 // used to mock multiple requests
  return poll(
    () => console.log(i) || Promise.resolve(i++ > 3), // the function you use to check completion
    () => Promise.resolve('result') // the function you use to get the results of the job
  );
}

isBatchRequestCompleted().then(console.log)
```

And the same idea with async/await:

```js
const delay = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

const poll = async (checkCompletion, resultsRequest) => {
  let done;
  
  do {
    done = await checkCompletion() // check for completion
  
    if(!done) await delay(1000) // delay if not done
  } while(!done) // continue loop if not done
  
  return resultsRequest() // return the results of calling the request
}

async function isBatchRequestCompleted() {
  let i = 0 // used to mock multiple requests
  return poll(
    () => console.log(i) || Promise.resolve(i++ > 3), // the function you use to check completion
    () => Promise.resolve('result') // the function you use to get the results of the job
  );
}

isBatchRequestCompleted().then(console.log)
```